# codeigniter - call model's function in view

Tags: php, mysql, database, codeigniter

Is it OK to call model's function in views?

I need to make a table with table-child insides it.

Just like this:

```
row1
    row1.1
    row1.2

row2
    row2.1
    row2.2

row3
    row3.1
    row3.2
```

**CONTROLLER:**

```
$data['test'] = $this->model_test->get_parent_row()->result_array();
$this->load->view('test_view', $data);
```

I use multi-foreach in views; first foreach to show every single parent row, and the sub-foreach to show the row-child. But it means I have to call a query to get the row-child based on the parent row.

Any advise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To keep the logic in the controller, I would recommend to create two different views. One with the child-row data, and one with the parent data. The secret is to pass the parameter `TRUE` when calling the view to return the data into a variable instead of printing it out to the browser. Something like this in the controller:

```
$parent = $this->model_test->get_parent_row()->result_array();

$children = ''; // INITIATE STRING TO STORE ALL CHILD VIEWS...

// LOOP THROUGH PARENTS...
foreach($parent as $child){
    // CREATE YOUR QUERY TO GET CHILD ROW HERE... 
    // ADJUST TO WHATEVER YOUR MODEL NAME OR PARAMETERS ARE:
    $child_row = $this->model->get_child_row($child)->result_array();

    // THE TRUE PARAMETER RETURNS DATA FROM THE VIEW INSTEAD OF OUTPUT TO THE BROWSER
    $children .= $this->load->view('child_view', $child_row, TRUE);     
}

$this->load->view('parent_view', array('test'=>$children));
```

Hope you understand the logic. Find more info about views in the documentation (scroll down to the end): https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/views.html

Easier would be to create a model that returns all data at once, and then pass the array to one view where you can loop through all parents and their children at once.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this array structure inside your model
Try below logic to maintain parent-child logic and you can directly pass it to your view.

On model:

```
function your_function_name() {
//select parent category

$parent_array = array();

$query1 = $this->db->get('parent-table');


foreach($query1->result() as $row1) {

    $child_array = array();

    // query for children

        $query2 = $this->db->get('chilr-table')->where(id, $row1['id']);

     foreach($query2->result() as $row2) {
        $child_array[] = array(
                        'id' => $row2['id'],
                        'name'      => $row2['name']
                    );
     }

     $parent_array[] = array(
                        'id' => $row1['filter_group_id'],
                        'name'   => $row1['name'],
                        'children'   => $child_array
                    );

}

return $parent_array;
}
```

On Controller :
Load your model

```
$this->load->model('model_name');
```

pass to view

```
$data['test'] = $this->model_name->your_function_name();
$this->load->view('test_view', $data);
```

I hope it will help you